# How can I mask or reduce the taste of coconut oil? Perhaps a spice of some sort?

Tags: flavor, oil, coconut, coconut-oil

I love it for its health benefits and I can't eat most other oils in higher amounts, but my meals are very fatty (and I intend to keep that that way), so that means a lot of coconut oil. However it's hard to eat the meals sometimes, while if I was to add butter - it would taste amazing (but I cannot eat butter or ghee unfortunately).

I know that one way is to use refined oil instead, but I'm not going to do that due to many health-related reasons.

So besides that, is there a way to reduce or mask the taste of coconut oil somehow? Some spice perhaps?

Comment: Have you considered peanuts to make coconut peanut butter? It's really the latest trend in mediocre foods, at least where I live. You can even just buy it, perhaps over the internet if it's not popular (yet?) where you live.

Comment: @Raditz_35 As much as I LOOOVE peanut butter (and peanuts), my gut doesn't like them nearly as much. :/ Coconut peanut butter sounds even more delicious... Maybe I'll make just a little bit to have half a spoon on days when I feel like having a nice treat. Thank you for suggesting! Adding to my notes :)

Comment: @Spagirl Interesting lingual note. Languages also interest me. Though here I'd prefer to focus on adding something that masks coconut oil taste to my foods, as I am planning to use it as butter substitute for everything (and I eat very fatty meals).

Comment: I think you're going to have trouble getting a great answer unless you make your question more specific. What types of foods are you cooking? What flavors do you prefer? I think the answer is probably "yes", but it depends on a lot of factors...

Comment: @Ispare I just cook buckwheat or potatoes or lentils every day and I don't add any flavors to them except for potatoes, but I will stop eating potatoes. I would love to add some spices to lentils or buckwheat, but I'm not sure what would fit them. So I cook them and mix them with butter for now without anything else, but when I run out of the butter that I bought discounted, I will switch to coconut oil instead. And as you can imagine, the taste will not be so good with just the coconut oil. As for flavors, it really depends on my mood, unless I don't understand the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try out *Centrifugal Virgin Coconut Oil*. (This type of coconut oil is extracted from coconut milk, in large centrifuges that rotate at high speed which separates the oil from the coconut milk). It is better than refined coconut oil in terms of nutrition, but has similar profile to it as it is thinner, with a milder coconutty flavour than cold-pressed Virgin coconut oil.

> Cold pressed VCO is often preferred by consumers seeking a more authentic coconut aroma and flavor. Centrifugal VCO may have a milder scent and taste due to potential exposure to higher temperatures during extraction.
>
> Cold pressed VCO is often regarded as superior in terms of maintaining the original quality and purity of the coconut oil due to its minimal processing. Centrifugal VCO may have a slightly lower quality due to the potential for heat-induced degradation. - *[Centrifugal VS Cold Pressed Virgin Coconut Oil](https://www.globalcocosugar.com/cold-pressed-virgin-coconut-oil/)*

I find that it strikes a good balance between nutrition and taste and is definitely much better than refined oils.

---

There's no magic spice that can make coconut oil taste better in any dish. It totally depends on what you actually cook, and what recipe you use. For example, this [Kerala Beef Fry recipe](https://youtu.be/0W6uY3_Jo3E) tastes great with coconut oil due to the variety of common indian spices it uses. I can also recommend [Kerala Fish Curry](https://youtu.be/Z3ylY7Xv3XE) and [Chicken Stew Kerala Style](https://youtu.be/FtRkDwWNgyE) that are usually had with rice or rice noodles. Adjust the spices according to your taste. (Kerala is a state in India that predominantly uses coconut oil in its cooking. So search for "Kerala recipes with coconut oil" in Youtube and experiment with those).

Also, if you find the taste of coconut oil overpowering, don't hesitate to use other vegetable based oils like Groundnut oil or Seasame Oil that are pretty common in India too and have been used here for centuries. Clarified butter (Ghee) is also good. I mostly prefer filtered Groundnut oil for most indian dishes, butter for western dishes, Seasame oil for Chinese cooking, and Coconut oil for South-indian dishes. For frying I use (horror!) Sunflower oil as it has a more neutral taste, has a higher smoke-point and is cheaper (I don't reuse frying oil more than twice so I cheap out by buying refined Sunflower oil - for all the rest I prefer buying the costlier cold-pressed extracted oil for the flavour and better nutrition profile). In other words, don't get stuck on just one oil because it is supposedly the best / latest "superfood". There is no single source of nutrition for us humans we need variety. Just experiment more with different ingredients and different dishes.

Comment: An excellent point about not getting hung up on the ‘best’.  You typically want to get a variety of foods so you’re not over loading on any one thing.  (Both so you can support a variety of gut bacteria, and so no chemical compounds are eaten to a point where they become problematic)