# How to make coconut oil taste better?

Tags: flavor, coconut-oil

I am starting oil pulling but I can not tolerate the taste in the morning. I’m already not a huge coconut taste person. What can I add to it to make it taste better?

Comment: You can buy deodorised coconut oil. Personally I can't see the point… but you can.

Comment: I would like to remind everybody that we are here to answer the question as asked, and not to discuss why the OP is eating pure coconut oil. The OP has chosen to consume something; telling them that they should consume something else instead is not constructive. Also, in this specific case, it may be a choice based on health beliefs - and we certainly don't want to start a discussion about these. So comments asking "why aren't you using some other oil" will be deleted.

Comment: @rumtscho oil pulling doesn’t involve consumption of the oil. It involves swilling it round your teeth and spitting it out.

Comment: @Spagirl thank you for explaining. In that case, people may decide to vote to close as not being about cooking food - let's see how the community reacts.

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/88319/how-can-i-mask-or-reduce-the-taste-of-coconut-oil-perhaps-a-spice-of-some-sort. Probably actually a duplicate, but of course unanswered. Also I recommend a read of my answer [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/95243/), the mechanisms are the same regardless of whether the smell got in there accidentally or is inherent in the foodstuff.